# Canonical form transformation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, canonical-transformation

​
​
My subject about the canonical form of PDE. I had many exercises to do and they were fine, but I'm stuck with this one: ​
​
$$U_{xx}-yU_{xy}+xU_x+yU_y+u=0$$​
​
So first we have to calculate $B-4AC=y^2-4​$. I couldn't determine what ether hyperbolic or elliptic or parabolic?​
​

Could you help me to get the canonical form? Thanks in advance.​

Comment: Please try to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This equation is hyperbolic.

First you look at only the second order stuff to get $u_{xx} - y u_{xy} = 0$.

This gives the auxiliary equation $v^2 - yv = 0$, which is $v(v-y) = 0$, giving two real distinct roots of $v = 0$, $v = y$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please use mathjax to format your answer.